# Expand text form on hover with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap text input and with jquery I would like to:

1. Expand textform on hover and retract on hover out.         ✓ ([already done in this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mY8uU/))
2. When textform is focused/selected (**insertion point is inside text box**), the form is expanded and does not retract on cursor hover out. ✗ (to be compelted)

**Html**

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search"></input>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function(){
  var form = $('.input-group');
  form.mouseenter(function(){
    form.animate({ "width": "+=" + form.width() * 1.4}, "slow");
  }).mouseout(function(){
    form.animate({ "width": '100%'}, "slow");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved http://jsfiddle.net/mY8uU/6/

```
$(function(){
  var form = $('.input-group'), w = form.width();
  form.mouseenter(function(){
    form.animate({'width': '100%'}, 'slow');
  }).mouseout(function(){         
    if(!$('.form-control:focus').length) form.animate({'width': w}, 'slow');
  })
  $('.form-control').on('blur', function(){
    form.animate({'width': w}, 'slow');
  });
});
```

Comment: @Neto's solution also works, but this is more concise, so the correct answer goes to you. Thankyou

Comment: thx! I will up Netos solution since he got there faster! (you do not need the console.log line)

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
$(function(){
  var form = $('.input-group');
  var start_width = form.width();

  form.find('#input-target').mouseenter(function(){
    form.animate({ "width": "+=" + start_width * 1.4}, "slow");
  }).mouseout(function(){
    form.animate({ "width": start_width+'px'}, "slow");
  }).focus(function(){
      $(this).unbind('mouseout');
      $(this).unbind('mouseenter');
  }).blur(function(){
      form.animate({ "width": start_width+'px'}, "slow");
      $(this).mouseout(function(){
        form.animate({ "width": start_width+'px'}, "slow");
      }).mouseenter(function(){
    form.animate({ "width": "+=" + start_width * 1.4}, "slow");
      });
  });
});
```

see at this
http://jsfiddle.net/ZQ3nZ/

Comment: This is exceptionally close to what i was looking for, there is one bug however. When selected hoverin still works making the input longer and longer

Comment: Oh, and you might want to unbind() the mouseenter as well, otherwise it will keep growing until it loses focus.

Answer (score 2):

Is CSS3 out of the question?

In that case you can do without Javascript and use

```
.textbox{
   width: 200px;
   transition: width 1S;
}

.textbox:hover
{
    width:250px;
    transition: width 1S;
}
```

This is just an example, but you can change it to your liking.

Answer (score 1):

You could always employ some CSS3:

```
input#search {
  transition: width .5s;
  -webkit-transition: width .5s;
}
input#search:hover, input#search:focus { width:300px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

this one worked for me:

```
$(function(){
  var form = $('.input-group');
  form.mouseenter(function(){
    form.animate({ "width":  form.width() * 1.8}, "slow");
  }).mouseout(function(){
    form.animate({ "width":  form.width() / 1.8}, "slow");
  });
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mY8uU/2/

Comment: This will work in this specific case, but if for some reason the width was further altered, dividing by 1.8 might not be the proper calculation. Just a heads up :) (this isn't wrong in the slightest so don't take this as criticism lol)

Comment: thank you @RUJordan but i hope he is creative enough to do the rest of the work by itself :) just trying to give some "working inputs" :)

Comment: This does not do what I am after. When the text form is selected (ie insertion point is inside the text box), hover out should not work, but when not selected, hoverout works.